# SignalR: notifying progress of lengthy operation from ASP.NET Core web API to Angular 7 client

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

**EDITED**: see at the bottom

I'm new to SignalR and trying to implement with it a simple scenario with Angular7 client using this library, and ASP.NET Core web API. All what I need is to use SignalR to notify the client about the progress of some lengthy operations in methods of the API controllers.

After a number of attempts, I got to a point where apparently the connection is established, but then when the long task starts running and sending messages, my client does not seem to receive anything, nor any traffic appears in web sockets (Chrome F12 - Network - WS).

I post here the details, which might also be useful to other newcomers (**full source code** at https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsHCfliT740PkZh4cHY3r7I8f-VQiQ). Probably I'm just making some obvious error, yet in the docs and googling around I could not find a code fragment essentially different from mine. Could anyone give a hint?

My start point for the server side was https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt846469.aspx, plus the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2. I tried to create a dummy experimental solution with that.

My code snippets in form of a recipe follow.

**(A) Server Side**

1.create a new ASP.NET core web API app. No authentication or Docker, just to keep it minimal.

2.add the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR`.

3.at `Startup.cs`, `ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // CORS
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            // https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2110 for AllowCredentials
            .AllowCredentials()
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }));
    // SignalR
    services.AddSignalR();
    
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

and the corresponding `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    // CORS
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    // SignalR: add to the API at route "/progress"
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<ProgressHub>("/progress");
    });
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

4.add a `ProgressHub` class, which just derives from Hub:

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{
}
```

5.add a `TaskController` with a method to start some lengthy operation:

```
[Route("api/task")]
[ApiController]
public class TaskController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHubContext<ProgressHub> _progressHubContext;
    
    public TaskController(IHubContext<ProgressHub> progressHubContext)
    {
        _progressHubContext = progressHubContext;
    }
    
    [HttpGet("lengthy")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Lengthy([Bind(Prefix = "id")] string connectionId)
    {
        await _progressHubContext
            .Clients
            .Client(connectionId)
            .SendAsync("taskStarted");
            
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Debug.WriteLine($"progress={i}");
            await _progressHubContext
                .Clients
                .Client(connectionId)
                .SendAsync("taskProgressChanged", i);
        }
        
        await _progressHubContext
            .Clients
            .Client(connectionId)
            .SendAsync("taskEnded");
            
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**(B) Client Side**

1.create a new Angular7 CLI app (without routing, just to keep it simple).

2.`npm install @aspnet/signalr --save`.

3.my `app.component` code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnectionBuilder, HubConnection, LogLevel } from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { TaskService } from './services/task.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private _connection: HubConnection;
  
  public messages: string[];
  
  constructor(private _taskService: TaskService) {
    this.messages = [];
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-signalr-chat-angular/
    this._connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
      .withUrl("http://localhost:44348/signalr/progress")
      .build();
      
    this._connection.on("taskStarted", data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    this._connection.on("taskProgressChanged", data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.messages.push(data);
    });
    this._connection.on("taskEnded", data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    
    this._connection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
      .catch(err => console.error('Error while establishing connection: ' + err));
  }
  
  public startJob() {
    this.messages = [];
    this._taskService.startJob('zeus').subscribe(
      () => {
        console.log('Started');
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Its minimalist HTML template:

```
<h2>Test</h2>
<button type="button" (click)="startJob()">start</button>
<div>
  <p *ngFor="let m of messages">{{m}}</p>
</div>
```

The task service in the above code is just a wrapper for a function which calls `HttpClient`'s `get<any>('https://localhost:44348/api/task/lengthy?id=' + id)`.

---

### EDIT 1

After some more experimenting, I came with these changes:

- use `.withUrl('https://localhost:44348/progress')` as suggested. It seems that now it no more triggers 404. Note the change: I replaced `http` with `https`.
- do not make the API method async as it seems that the `await` are not required (i.e. set the return type to `IActionResult` and remove `async` and `await`).

With these changes, *I can now see the expected log messages on the client side* (Chrome F12). Looking at them, it seems that the connection gets bound to a generated ID `k2Swgcy31gjumKtTWSlMLw`:

```
Utils.js:214 [2019-02-28T20:11:48.978Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
Utils.js:214 [2019-02-28T20:11:48.987Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'.
Utils.js:214 [2019-02-28T20:11:48.988Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://localhost:44348/progress/negotiate.
core.js:16828 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
Utils.js:214 [2019-02-28T20:11:49.237Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
Utils.js:210 [2019-02-28T20:11:49.377Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44348/progress?id=k2Swgcy31gjumKtTWSlMLw.
Utils.js:214 [2019-02-28T20:11:49.378Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.
Utils.js:210 [2019-02-28T20:11:49.380Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'json'.
Utils.js:214 [2019-02-28T20:11:49.533Z] Debug: Server handshake complete.
app.component.ts:39 Connection started!
app.component.ts:47 Task service succeeded
```

So, it might be the case that I get no notification because my client ID does not match the ID assigned by SignalR (from the paper quoted above I had the impression that it was my duty to provide an ID, given that it is an argument of the API controller). Yet, I cannot see any available method or property in the connection prototype allowing me to retrieve this ID, so that I can pass it to the server when launching the lengthy job. Could this be the reason of my issue? If this is so, there should be a way of getting the ID (or setting it from the client side). What do you think?

Comment: Did u get any messages in the console?

Comment: You can get the connection ID as shown in my answer 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems I've finally found it. The issue was probably caused by the wrong ID, so I started looking for a solution. A post (https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2200) guided me to the usage of groups, which seems the recommended solution in these cases. So, I changed my hub so that it automatically assign the current connection ID to a "progress" group:

```
public sealed class ProgressHub : Hub
{
    public const string GROUP_NAME = "progress";

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        // https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2200
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups
        return Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "progress");
    }
}
```

Now, my API controller method is:

```
[HttpGet("lengthy")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Lengthy()
{
    await _progressHubContext
        .Clients
        .Group(ProgressHub.GROUP_NAME)
        .SendAsync("taskStarted");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Debug.WriteLine($"progress={i + 1}");
        await _progressHubContext
            .Clients
            .Group(ProgressHub.GROUP_NAME)
            .SendAsync("taskProgressChanged", i + 1);
    }
    await _progressHubContext
        .Clients
        .Group(ProgressHub.GROUP_NAME)
        .SendAsync("taskEnded");

    return Ok();
}
```

And of course I updated the client code accordingly, so that it does no more have to send an ID when invoking the API method.

Full demo repository available at https://github.com/Myrmex/signalr-notify-progress.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can get the connectionId as shown in my answer like this: `this.hubConnection.connectionId` and append it to your post/whatever request to ensure that progress is only sent to that particular client.

Answer (score 1):

You set the route for the hub as `/progress`, but then you're attempting to connect to `/signalr/progress`, which is going to be a 404. If you open the developer console, you should have an connection error there telling you as much.

Comment: Thanks, no error in the console. Just the diagnostic information: Debug: Starting HubConnection. || Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'. ||
Debug: Sending negotiation request: http://localhost:44348/signalr/progress/negotiate. I too had started with just `/progress`, but I got a 404 with this URL. I had to add `/signalr` to make the connection work and the negotiation happen. Further, when I click the button I can see that the server code gets invoked, and follow it with the debugger.

Comment: For repro purposes, I added a link to my source code at the head of the post.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that OP was on the right track with the connection ID.

I send it along optionally in the form data.

I'm just reporting progress while uploading to AWS and I handle with SignalR like this:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost("MyPostRoute")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFiles([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files, [FromForm] string? connectionId)
{
    await _logic.UploadFiles(files, connectionId);
    return Ok();
}
```

**Logic**

```
public async Task<bool> UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> files, string? connectionId)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Guid fileGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        using (var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(_awsClient))
        {
            var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
            {
                BucketName = _configuration["AwsBucket"],
                Key = fileGuid + extension,
                InputStream = file.OpenReadStream()
            };
            if (connectionId != null)
            {
                AwsFileProgress progress = new()
                {
                    ConnectionId = connectionId,
                    FileName = file.FileName
                };
                request.UploadProgressEvent += (sender, e) => Request_UploadProgressEvent(sender, e, progress);
            }
            await transferUtility.UploadAsync(request);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private async void Request_UploadProgressEvent(object? sender, UploadProgressArgs e, AwsFileProgress progress)
{
    progress.ProgressPercent = e.PercentDone;
    await _hub.Clients.Client(progress.ConnectionId).SendAsync("AWSProgress", progress);
}
```

I made a model for the progress stuff:

```
public class AwsFileProgress
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int ProgressPercent { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

And finally, the front-end:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";
import { environment } from "@environment";
import { AwsFileProgress } from "@models/signalr/awsFileProgress";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AwsSignalRService {
    private hubConnection!: signalR.HubConnection
    public data!: AwsFileProgress;
    public startConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .withUrl(`${environment.signalRhubRoot}/awsprogresshub`)
                            .build();
    this.hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => { console.log('AWS SignalR Service Connection started') })
        .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting AWS SignalR Service WebSocket: ' + err))
    }
    
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //This is all you have to do to get the connection ID:
    public getConnectionId() : string | null {
        return this.hubConnection.connectionId;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public addAwsProgressListener = () => {
        this.hubConnection.on('AWSProgress', (awsFileProgress : AwsFileProgress) => {
            this.data = awsFileProgress;
            console.log(awsFileProgress.progressPercent);
        });
    }
}
```

Then the actual component it's injected into:

```
import { AwsSignalRService } from "@shared/services/aws-signalr-service";

@Component({
  selector: 'settings',
  templateUrl: './settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings.component.scss'],
})
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private awsSignalRService: AwsSignalRService
  ) {
    awsSignalRService.startConnection();
    awsSignalRService.addAwsProgressListener();
  }
```

^ Whatever is in our progress listener is handled here.

Making the request (and reporting client-side upload progress) is handled like this.

Note that I just use a basic `(change)` handler on a file input (`<input type="file"  (change)="fileUploadTest($event)"/>`)

```
fileUploadTest(e: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    var cId = this.awsSignalRService.getConnectionId();
    for(let file of e.target.files as File[]) {
      formData.append('files', file, file.name);
    };
    if(cId != null)
      formData.append('connectionId',cId);
    const url: string = `${environment.ApiRoot}/MyPostRoute`;
    this.http.post<any>(url,formData, { 
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'
    }).subscribe({
      next: (response) => console.log(response),
      error: (error) => console.log(error)
    });
}
```

And the results in console of my API uploading data to AWS:

[image: Results]

Comment: I just wanted to add that if you use SkipNegotiation, you can request the ConnectionId from the server after you make your initial connection. Just invoke "RequestConnectionId" on the frontend and have the server reply with the Context.ConnectionId. Done.

Comment: When you skip negotiation, the initial negotiation step that usually retrieves the `connectionId` and available transports is skipped. This means the client tries to establish a direct WebSocket connection without having a `connectionId` upfront.

However, once the connection is established on the server side, the server assigns a `connectionId` to that connection. So when the server sends a message to the client through methods like `Clients.Caller.SendAsync(...)`, the client should then be aware of its `connectionId`.

Comment: If the server never sent a message to the client after the connection was established, then the client might not be aware of its `connectionId`. But as soon as the server sends a message to that client (e.g., using the `OnConnectedAsync` method), the client should have its `connectionId`.


This is a subtlety that might not be immediately obvious when using `SkipNegotiation`, but it's an important detail to keep in mind when designing the flow of your application.